# Update data without reloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, web

I want to update some data (CPU usage) on a web page using Nodejs. I would like to use a web framework (I use EJS right now). Can I do this without an API? Is there any library that supports this? Sorry if it's a stupid question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+continuous+update+page+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: socket.io? Or you can also try polling ?(sending an ajax request to server in certain time interval) to fetch the latest data?